# Load IP address with data coming from a GPS device

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, ip, vps

I want to have an IP address which when pinged will load all the data sent from a GPS device. The GPS device is configured to send data to an IP address and port. I need to run a server side script to read the data from that port and display it on the IP address. Does GCP provide a static IP address to be purchased and can I use Google Cloud functions or any other GCP tool  to read data from that specific port and display it on that IP address? If yes, how could I go about doing this? And is there any other way to implement this using some other platform?

Answer (score 0):

> Does GCP provide a static IP address to be purchased

Yes, you can create a static public IP address in Google Cloud.

Public IP addresses are free when attached to running instances/services.

[Reserving a Static External IP Address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address)

> can I use Google Cloud functions or any other GCP tool to read data
>   from that specific port and display it on that IP address?

You have not provided enough information to answer this part of your question.

Do not mix multiple topics into one question. Create separate questions. You will get more/better answers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am able to reserve a static external IP address however whenever I try to access this IP, it refuses connection and doesn't load. Is there any specific way to acces the IP address on the web once you reserve it?